# php to add a link into wp widget without specific url

Tags: widgets, links

I'm trying to write a plugin to a specific page that the plugin creates. The issue is how do i add a link to that page from the widget. I know the page but the url has to be picked up from the site it is installed on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the get_page_link() function:

http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_link/

I found it by searching for "get page link" here:

http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/